# product of all the integers less than or equal to n having same remainders when divided by m and are also equal to n%m

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

Given two integers **n** and **m**, what is the product of all the integers **<= n** having same remainders when divided by the number **m** and the remainders are equal to **n%m**? As the numbers can be too large find the **product % (10^9+7)**

Here $0<=n<=2*10^9$, $1<=m<=2*10^9$ and $n/m<=10^6$

As the constraints are too large I need a simple way to find the answer

Example:
For **n=8** and **m=3**, there are three numbers: **2,5 and 8<=n** which give same remainders when divided my **m=3** and the remainders are also equal to **n%m** , i.e,**2** so the answer is $2*8*5=80$. Now the final answer is **80 modulus (10^9+7)** which equals **80**

So I need a simpler way to evaluate the answer for larger values of **n and m**

Comment: But also $1, 4, 7$ have the same remainder, so?

Comment: I did miss out a vital point in the question @Andreas Caranti, I have edited it

Comment: Note that you have $\lfloor \frac nm \rfloor$ numbers to multiply, many of which are of order $n$.  With your constants, the result could be as large as $(10^9)^{10^6}$ which has $9,000,000$ digits.  Are you prepared for that?  Do you need an exact answer or is an approximate one (say the log of the answer) acceptable?

Comment: @RossMilikan it would be better if we find the answer %(10^9 +7)

Comment: Yes, that changes the question completely.  Is that what you are looking for?  If so, please edit it in.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you can write an explicit formula of $\prod_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac n m\rfloor}(remainder(n,m)+m i)$

Comment: Can someone please clarify the meaning of the symbol "%"? e.g., what is 12 % 5?

Comment: @DavidR. "%" means modulus